# How do I pass an expression as a function keyword in Python

Tags: python, pandas, expression, keyword

I am trying to be pythonic with my code but can't figure out how to do:

```
dfSort.assign(i+5=pd.Series(dfWork))
```

where dfSort is a Dataframe and pd is pandas import. Of course the `i+5` is an expression and therefore cannot be passed as a column name. But I want to assign a column name dynamically in code (called `i+5`). The only way to do this otherwise is (this can get cumbersome):

```
if (i+5)== 5:
    dfSort =  dfSort.assign(a=pd.Series(dfWork, index=dfSort.index.values))

elif (i+5)==6:
    dfSort =  dfSort.assign(b=pd.Series(dfWork, index=dfSort.index.values))

elif (i+5)==7:   
    dfSort =  dfSort.assign(c=pd.Series(dfWork, index=dfSort.index.values))

elif (i+5)==8:   
    dfSort =  dfSort.assign(d=pd.Series(dfWork, index=dfSort.index.values))
```

Is there a way to do this like the first code block without the if statements?

This doesn't work:

```
Colname = {5: 'a',6 : 'b', 7 : 'c', 8 : 'd'}   
dfSort =  dfSort.assign(Colname[i+5]=pd.Series(dfWork) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dfWork` is a `pd.Series` type, then you can use dictionary unpacking, as Ashwini mentions, like this:

```
Colname = {5: 'a',6 : 'b', 7 : 'c', 8 : 'd'}  
i = ... # an integer

dfSort = dfSort.assign(**{ Colname[i + 5] : pd.Series(dfWork, index=dfSort.index.values) })
```

Demo:

```
In [625]: df
Out[625]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  3  4
1  2  4  5
2  3  5  6

In [627]: df.assign(**{Colname[i + 5] : pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], index=df.index.values)})
Out[627]: 
   0  1  2  b
0  1  3  4  a
1  2  4  5  b
2  3  5  6  c
```

You can pass a dictionary with multiple k:v pairs, and perform assignment for multiple columns at the same time.

Comment: Hi, okay thanks. I had tried this `dfSort =  dfSort.assign(**Colname[i+4] = pd.Series(dfWork) )` It turns out I needed to add {} and use the Colon.

Comment: @DrizztVD I don't. I thought you had gotten an error. I misread your comment. My bad.